# Apex Email Error: Invalid toAddress

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage

I am receiving the following exception when trying to send an email through Apex:

> Exception: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on
>   row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email address is invalid:
>   "jfort@gmail.com": [toAddresses,
>   "jfort@gmail.com"]

Apex code to send email:

```
    try {
        // Create an email invitation for everyone in the contacts list
        if (!contacts.isEmpty()) {
            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            for (String contact : contacts) {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                System.debug('TO ADDRESS: ' + new String[] {contact});
                email.setToAddresses(new String[] {contact});
                email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId('0D250000000TQTP') ;
                email.setSubject('Invitation');
                email.setHtmlBody('Please click the link to accept invitation: <a href="' + invitationURL + '">Invitation</a>' );
                emails.add(email);
            }  

        // Send the email invitations
        List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> sendEmailResults = Messaging.sendEmail(emails); 

        // Returns feedback message if email was sent successfully or not 
        for (Messaging.SendEmailResult result : sendEmailResults) {
            if (result.IsSuccess()) {
                emailSent = true;
                System.debug('Email sent successfully!');
            } else {
                System.debug('There was an error. The email was not sent.');
                System.StatusCode statusCode = result.getErrors()[0].getStatusCode();
                String errorMsg = result.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
                System.debug('Status code: ' + statusCode);
                System.debug('Error msg: ' + errorMsg);
            }
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.debug('Exception: ' + e);
}
}
```

Can anyone shine some light on this issue? It will send the email successfully when I hardcode the contact email like so `email.setToAddresses(new String[] {'jfort@gmail.com'})` but not when I dynamically set the address.

**EDIT:**

```
    public void sendInvitations() {
    // Send out email invites to all contacts on list
    if (emailAddresses != null) {
        sendHigiInvite.sendEmail(emailAddresses, UserInfo.getSessionId());
        }
    }
```

`contacts` gets passed to this email method as a parameter `List<String>`. I check if it is null before passing it to the method. My log shows this as the value for `contacts`

> 10:22:03:007 USER_DEBUG [28]|DEBUG|CONTACTS: ("jfort@gmail.com", "jfortich@yahoo.com")

Comment: can you take one contact record from the query criteria and see if the user has access to the record

Comment: Where are you getting `contacts`? Are you sure it does not contain any `null` values?

Comment: Can you also post how you are building the contacts (List of string)

Comment: Do you perhaps have the quotes in the included string? As in `"aaa@gmail.com"` instead of just `aaa@gmail.com`?

Comment: Hi everyone-- I updated my post with additional information. `contacts` gets passed as a `List<String>` parameter and I validate that it is not null before passing it into the sendEmail method

Comment: I am sure what sebastian pointed is what is happening, add this line after the start of the for loop and let us know if the error gets fixed      contact = contact.replace('\"','');

Comment: It worked! Thanks guys! Does salesforce usually include the quotations when reading strings from a list?

Comment: I assume not, but how are you building the email list, is the source field an email type or string type?

Comment: @SebastianKessel please post your comment as an answer, great observation could have never gussed the "" getting added looking at the error message

Comment: Hmm I think I see what happened now. I build the email list from a Standard Set Controller that retrieves selected contacts from a list view and puts them into a list. I then serialize the emails into JSON in order to pass the list to a future method. It must be when I serialize the emails addresses that the quotes are included.

Comment: Also just a reminder strings are immutable and you need to reassign the string value instead of just doing a string.replace() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you perhaps have the quotes in the included string? As in "aaa@gmail.com" instead of just aaa@gmail.com? That could be it.

Comment: Thank you! Would have never guessed the quotations were the issue

Comment: You work in SFDC long enough, you see it all. :D